# Asset to vs asset for

Tags: prepositions

I believe my skills will be an asset **to** the company.

I believe my skills will be an asset **for** the company.

Concerning the meaning in this context, the Cambridge dictionary defines the word asset to mean a valuable person or thing and suggests that the word is used with **to**. I would like to know if **for** is wrong here. Or if they both mean the same thing and are acceptable in written form.

Comment: ***to*** is unquestionably more common in your exact context, but ***for*** is perfectly acceptable and carries no significantly different connotations. You'll also often see ***of***, particularly in more "legal" contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference her is:

"My skills will be an asset to..." implies that the skills will come 'to' the company, and do work there. This would be the more common use.

"My skills will be an asset for..." implies that the company will be able to put the skills to use somewhere. The impression is more outward focused... like if the company will use those skills in dealing with the outward world.

All in all a subtle difference, but the first is to be preferred most of the time.